# How to add event listener using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Have this code and tried to hide my side `navbar` when clicked outside the `#nav`, got this error.

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.menu-opener').click(function(){
            $('#nav').toggleClass('active');
        });
        let slide = document.querySelector('#nav .active');
        slide.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            if (e.target !== slide) return;
            $('#nav').removeClass('active'); 
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Please post your HTML code so we can see what your functions are referencing.

Comment: document.querySelector is returning null when element is not present on web page. So you can just put if condition before applying addEventListener method. Like as below: if( document.querySelector('#nav .active') != null ) {/* Code goes after this comment */}

Comment: why the setTimeout call ?

Comment: Set time was already there before. #nav is a list coming from left when a press a button wich adds the class 'active'. I think that the element is null just because on load the page have only the id nav and when i press the button the .active class is removed

Answer (score 0):

answer is that you need to detect click outside of div you are trying to hide:

```
$(window).click(function() {
//Hide the menus if visible
});

//stopping above function from  running when clicking on #nav itself
$('#nav').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside setTimeout

```
$('body').on('click','#nav .active', function(e){
   // your logic
})
```

OR

```
$( "'#nav .active'" ).bind( "click", function(e) {
// your logic
});
```

instead of

```
let slide = document.querySelector('#nav .active');
        slide.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            if (e.target !== slide) return;
            $('#nav').removeClass('active'); 
        });
```

Comment: TypeError: $(...).on is not a function this is the error message i got on this!

Comment: Method on was introduced in jQuery version 1.7. Might be you have lower version

Answer (score 0):

Got this working with

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('#nav').length && !$(event.target).closest(".menu-opener").length)
    {
        $('#nav').removeClass('active');
    }        
});
```